# LLVM alias analyzer weird results

Tags: c++, pointers, compiler-construction, llvm

I'm implementing a pass that uses alias analyzer, specially using the AliasSetTracker. I simply want to output all alias sets in a function.

The pass code is very simple, it runs on functions and it is like this:

```
virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &F) {
  AliasAnalysis &AA = getAnalysis<AliasAnalysis>();

  AliasSetTracker tr(AA);
  for(Function::iterator i=F.begin();i!=F.end();++i){

    for(BasicBlock::iterator j=i->begin();j!=i->end();++j){
  if(dyn_cast<StoreInst>(j)){
            StoreInst *ai=dyn_cast<StoreInst>(j);
    //errs().write_escaped(ai->getName());
      tr.add(ai);
  }
  if(dyn_cast<LoadInst>(j)){
            LoadInst *ai=dyn_cast<LoadInst>(j);
    //errs().write_escaped(ai->getName());
      tr.add(ai);
  }
}

int counter=0;
for(AliasSetTracker::iterator it=tr.begin();it!=tr.end();++it){
  errs() << "Set " << counter++ << "\n";
  AliasSet *s=dyn_cast<AliasSet>(it);
  if(s->isMustAlias())
    errs() << " set is must alias\n";
  if(s->isMayAlias())
    errs() << " set is may alias\n";
  for(AliasSet::iterator ra=s->begin();ra!=s->end();++ra){

    errs() << ra.getPointer()->getName() << " ";
  }

}
  }
  return true;
}
```

I test the pass with the following test function implement in hello.cpp:

```
void testfuncion(int *given){
  int *o,*i;
  o=given;
  i=NULL;
}
```

I run the plugin using different AA passes e.g.:

```
clang  -emit-llvm -o hello.bc -c hello.cpp -> compile the test code
./opt -load ../lib/AliasTest.so -globalsmodref-aa -aliastoprolog < hello.bc OR
./opt -load ../lib/AliasTest.so -basicaa -aliastoprolog < hello.bc
```

In the test function as you can see i and o are not aliases. With globalsmodref, the pass prints may alias.
With basicaa *o* and *i* are in separate sets (correctly) but when I change the line *i=NULL* to *i=o* in the test function, basicaa still returns separate sets for *o* and *i*, globalsmodref says o and i may alias even though it should be must alias. So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think `AliasSet *s=dyn_cast<AliasSet>(it);` is the right way to get the `AliasSet`s. Use getAliasSets() method instead as shown in the link below.

http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1AliasSetTracker.html#a8f3b5f5d7978436b03d3e4b8597d9bc4

Does it make a difference ?

Comment: I basically checked the generated ir and I see in the code the basic aliasing pattern. With a statement like this i=o, the ir has %3=load i32** o, align 4 then store i32* %3, i32** %i, align 4 . However, the alias analyzer result says i and o are not aliases (No Alias). This is very strange.